# Oracle Data Access ORA-06512: character string buffer too small

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net

When I call `GetTest` I get this error:

> string buffer too small ORA-06512

This my c# method:

```
public string GetTEST()
{
    using (var conn = new OracleConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Dbconnection"].ConnectionString))
    {
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("Package.GetTEST");
        cmd.BindByName = true;
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("P_OUT_MESSAGE", OracleDbType.Varchar2,1000,ParameterDirection.Output);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        var t = cmd.Parameters["P_OUT_MESSAGE"].Value;
    }
}
```

Oracle Procedure:

```
PROCEDURE GetTEST
(
  P_OUT_MESSAGE    OUT VARCHAR2 
)
IS
BEGIN
  p_out_message := 'Un problème a été signalé pour votre propriété. Veuillez communiquer avec le Service de l''évaluation au 418 111-7878 ou à l''adresse test@tesst.com';
END;
```

Comment: What is the purpose of specifying a size of 9999999999999999999?

Comment: To be sure that p_out_message size is sufficient...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is obviously not what you want, but it seems that ODP.NET uses the length of the parameter at the .NET side as the length of the out parameter...

This will fix your issue:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("P_OUT_MESSAGE", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 32767, "x".PadRight(500, 'x'), ParameterDirection.Output);
```

But this is nicer, and although not entirely correct, it works:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("P_OUT_MESSAGE", OracleDbType.Clob, ParameterDirection.Output);
```

Or, even better, if possible, avoid the use of `out` parameters and use scalar return values or table functions.

Comment: Yes, it does. I even tried the new Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, but it fails too.

Comment: This didn't work for me but I'm not going to downvote as it's clear that it works for some folks.

Comment: @dan: thanks for commenting. Can you elaborate on the 'not working' part? Maybe you can ask a new question, refer to this one and maybe we can find something that does work for you.

Comment: @PatrickHofman When trying both solutions, I still get `ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: NULL index table key value`.

Comment: @dan can it be related to another problem in your code. It seems that it is related to the function's internal code. See [here](http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/14998/).

Comment: @PatrickHofman I asked our DBA about it and he assures me that the code is okay. I know SQL but don't know the finer points of PLSQL so I have to take him at his word. Also, if I execute the same call via SQLPlus or Toad for example, it *does* work, so it does suggest that something isn't correct on the ODP side. All I'm doing is passing in a string so nothing fancy in the request.

Answer (score 0):

You must use 5 parameters for the OUT parameter of procedure. So I added null here:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("P_OUT_MESSAGE", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 1000, null, ParameterDirection.Output)
```

with 4 it treats 1000 as object value and not as size.